# json file not loading on server but works locally - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to load data from data.json using angularjs.

```
var app= angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("MyFunction", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
        {    
            $http.get('js/data.json').success (function(data){
                $scope.mydata = data;
        });

        }]
);
```

data.json loads the content locally but not on server. Please help.

Comment: There can be various reasons. What you should do is to open Chrome Developer Tools and look tab Network. You might just find that the result is 404 because the url is build in a wrong way. That's my guess.

Comment: @DavidBohunek, yes you are right, its giving 404, it doesn't load the json file. but it loads locally and works fine. what could be wrong? Pls help!

Comment: if you have reference to this file in head `data.json` then try removing after it. and try clearing cache.

Comment: Is the url of the request returning 404 correct?

Comment: yes. i also tried using the full url. still it doesn't work

Comment: Right. It is still just guessing but try what I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have json as a valid allowed mime type in your server settings.

Comment: can I please know how to do that?